# vmstat doesn't return the correct value on the first time run

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmstat

I am using `vmstat` on ubuntu linux to get cpu usage. My current cpu is very busy at almost 100%. If I run `vmstat` like below:

```
$ vmstat     
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 8  1      0 6383924 1287224 18123836    0    0     2    53    2   16  1  1 98  0  0
```

it shows the cpu idle is 98%. But if I run it with a delay and count like below:

```
$ vmstat 2 2
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 5  1      0 6491296 1287268 18128956    0    0     2    53    3   17  1  1 98  0  0
 4  1      0 6491992 1287268 18129080    0    0     0  2264 11142 17980 98  2  0  0  0
```

it shows the correct cpu usage starting from the second time. My question is why it can't output the correct value for the first time run.

Comment: why is it a normal behaviour? If it is true, that means I can't run `vmstat` without any parameters because it always returns wrong output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man vmstat` (bold emphasis added by me):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> `vmstat [options] [delay [count]]`
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `vmstat`  reports  information about processes, memory, paging, block IO, traps, disks and cpu activity.
>
> **The first report produced gives averages since the last reboot.**
>
> Additional  reports  give information on a sampling period of length delay.  The process and memory reports are instantaneous in either case.
>
> **OPTIONS**
>
> `delay`  The delay between updates in seconds.  **If no delay is specified, only one report is printed with the average values since boot.**
>
> `count`  Number  of updates.  In absence of count, when delay is defined, default is infinite.
>
> [...]

Comment: `man`
 to the rescue. I remembered something on that line, but could not put my finger to it.